# How can I fill a temporary file with content?

Tags: java, temporary

I wrote a method which reads .properties files. I tested my method with real files on my pc and it worked. But now I want to use temporary files to make sure my unit tests works even if I delete my test resource. 
I tried:

```
@Rule
 public TemporaryFolder tmpFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
 public void loadPropertiesFromFile(){
     File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".properties", tmpFolder.getRoot()); 
}
```

But how can I write content in my tmpFile like "key1=foo1"?

Comment: First things first, this is 2016; why use `File` at all? You use Java 7+, right?

Comment: No, I'm using Java 8. But I'm new to it...

Comment: 8 is 7+ (7+ means 7 or more). Which means you can use the new file API which doesn't require you to use `File`, which is [broken](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). You can use [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem) in your tests: if they work with this, they will work everywhere.

Comment: @fge Thank you, I will be saving that first link for future use.  The number of new SO questions using java.io.File is staggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called `temp.properties`, write your content (i.e. key1=foo1, etc) and use the File Api.

```
@Test
 public void loadPropertiesFromFile(){
     File tmpFile = new File("temp.properties"); //put absolute path of file in argument.

 }
```